# Why do my questions never get answered on SU?

Tags: discussion, questions

Ok, so some of my questions get answered after a long time on SU, but many of my questions site idle for much longer than I'm used to on the SE network.  I'm used to answer times of *a day*, not no answer in *weeks*.

Am I doing something wrong?  Are my questions not clear, or are they lacking some important documentation?  Am I not asking in the right place?  How do I get my questions answered on SU?

- [How can I add a list to Infopath drop down?](https://superuser.com/questions/208937/how-can-i-add-a-list-to-infopath-drop-down) (Need to self answer)
- [Is it possible to unpublish an InfoPath template?](https://superuser.com/questions/209103/is-it-possible-to-unpublish-an-infopath-template) (One wrong answer, need to self answer)
- [Set two values based on a single drop down in InfoPath](https://superuser.com/questions/209487/set-two-values-based-on-a-single-drop-down-in-infopath) (Need to self answer)
- [Zoneminder camera permanently idle](https://superuser.com/questions/150216/zoneminder-camera-permanently-idle) (Who knows)
- [Notepad++ Reindent XML breaks lines.](https://superuser.com/questions/219852/notepad-reindent-xml-breaks-lines)
- [Stop Outlook 2007 from creating tasks for everything tagged in Gmail?](https://superuser.com/questions/219915/stop-outlook-2007-from-creating-tasks-for-everything-tagged-in-gmail)
- [Can I change the system bell noise in Exceed?](https://superuser.com/questions/205775/can-i-change-the-system-bell-noise-in-exceed)
- [How can I copy text from Exceed?](https://superuser.com/questions/204482/how-can-i-copy-text-from-exceed)

Comment: Perhaps try a bit simpler questions? ;-) I don't know over half of your tools

Comment: yes, your toolchain does not resemble mine.. InfoPath is a specialty for sure, and Exceed I have not heard of.

Comment: @Jeff It's a shame, I love the SE network, but SU doesn't seem to work for "All personal computer hardware and software".

Comment: ross well, it's the same thing on http://webapps.stackexchange.com which is about "the whole internet". In practice that means the *popular* parts of the internet. Questions about Uncle Lou's Dipstick Factory webapp will go unanswered..

Comment: No need to complain about it. If the tool is not-so-widely-used, it's ok when such questions get no/less answers. If the tool becomes famous and has a lot of users, some of good people will enter SE to help others. Perhaps you can be the first good user who can help others in such tools :-)

Answer (score 11):

**Some of the issues that I can see here are:**

1. InfoPath and Exceed (at least for me and probably for many others) isn't a widely used program, and therefore may not attract as many answers.
2. Although some of us have Super human powers here at Super User, questions don't always get answered right away.
3. Perhaps more detail *may* be of some help as it seems that most of your questions are only a single sentence or two. (didn't really read through all of them to see)

**Things that you can do:**

1. Put a bounty on the questions that you feel really need to be looked at
2. Edit you questions to clarify the question/bring the question back up to the front of the Super User Home page.